# @stomp/stompjs/esm6 connection in React is not working after porting to newest releases

Tags: reactjs, websocket, stompjs

I am doing my first react project, which is to port a demo web page what is using react 16 @stomp/stompjs/esm6 to talk to the back end.  After recoding to use react 18.2 and the stomp 6 version, the connection is not working as before.  It decides to upgrade to websocket when the server is not up and starts printing out "WebSocket error: Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)" to the terminal.  Below is the code before and after:

before code:

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^5.4.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.3",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.5.0",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.75",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
```

setupProxy.js

```
    const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

    module.exports = function(app) {
        app.use(proxy("/ws", {target: "http://localhost:8080", ws: true}));
    }
```

WsConstants.js - I am connecting as /ws in debug

```
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";

let backendApiUrl;      // how you are going to connect to the socket
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // dev
    backendApiUrl = '/ws';
} else {
    // production http://localost:8080/ws
    backendApiUrl = window['runConfig'].backendApiUrl;
}
export const SOCKET = () => new SockJS(backendApiUrl);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Mcd from "../mcd/Mcd";
import StitchingTool from "../stitching/StitchingTools";
import BoundingTool from "../bounding/BoundingTools";
import PtzToPanoTool from "../ptztopano/PtzToPanoTools";

import LocationTool from "../location/LocationTools";
import {SOCKET} from "../../models/app/WsConstants";
import {Stomp} from "@stomp/stompjs/esm6";
import * as actionTypes from "./store/actionTypes";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Layout from "./Layout";

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stompClient: Stomp.over(SOCKET),
            cameras: {}
        };

        // comment out to enable Stomp's logging...
        this.state.stompClient.debug = ()=>{};

        this.state.stompClient.reconnectDelay = 3000;
        this.state.stompClient.onConnect = () => this.handleWsConnect(this.state.stompClient);
        this.state.stompClient.onDisconnect = this.handleWsDisconnect;
        this.state.stompClient.onStompError = this.handleWsDisconnect;
        this.state.stompClient.onWebSocketClose = this.handleWsDisconnect;
        this.state.stompClient.onWebSocketError = this.handleWsDisconnect;
        this.state.stompClient.activate();
    }

    handleWsConnect = (stompClient) => {
        console.log(' ------------ WS CONNECTED! ------------ ');
        stompClient.subscribe("/mcd/cameras", (res) => {
            this.setState({...this.state, cameras: JSON.parse(res.body || '{}')});
        });
        stompClient.send("/mcd/cameras");

        this.props.onWsConnected();
    }

    handleWsDisconnect = (event) => {
        console.error(' ------------ WS DISCONNECTED! ------------\n' + JSON.stringify(event));
        this.props.onWsDisconnected();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (!this.state.stompClient) {
            this.state.stompClient.deactivate();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout wsConnected={this.props.app.wsConnected}>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Mcd stompClient={this.state.stompClient}/>}/>
                        <Route path="/stitchingtool" render={() => <StitchingTool cameras={this.state.cameras} stompClient={this.state.stompClient}/>}/>
                        <Route path="/boundingtool" render={() => <BoundingTool stompClient={this.state.stompClient}/>}/>
                        <Route path="/ptztopanotool" render={() => <PtzToPanoTool stompClient={this.state.stompClient}/>}/>
                        {/*<Route path="/overlaytool" render={() => <OverlayTool stompClient={this.state.stompClient}/>}/>*/}
                        <Route path="/locationtool" render={() => <LocationTool stompClient={this.state.stompClient}/>}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

New code:
package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.10",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
```

setupProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware("/ws", {target: "http://localhost:8080", ws: true}));
}
```

WsConstants.js is unchanged:

App.js

```
/*
This class is to create a navigation bar at the top of the web page.
The selected action will then be loaded in the bottom half of the web page.
*/

import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {SOCKET} from "../../models/app/WsConstants";
import {Stomp} from "@stomp/stompjs/esm6";

import Mcd from "../mcd/Mcd";
import LocationTool from "../location/LocationTool";
import NoPage from "../nav/NoPage";
import {Navbar, NavLayout} from "../nav/Navbar";

/*
This is the main entry point into the web page which is divided in to two rows where
the top is the navigation bar.

The Mcd is the default page.  Add new pages by adding a new Route block.
*/
function App() {
  const [wsConnected, setWsConnected] = useState(false);
  const wsSetupComplete = useRef(false);
  var stompClient = useRef(Stomp.over(SOCKET));

  /*
  Setup the web socket connect overhead.  This will only be done once on page load.
  */
  const connectAndSetupOnlyOnce = () => {
      // Did we already setup the socket?
      if (wsSetupComplete.current) {
        return;
      }

       // comment out to enable Stomp's logging...
       stompClient.current.debug = () => {};
       // enable Stomp's logging...
       //stompClient.current.debug = function(str) {
       //    console.log(str);
       // }

        // automatically reconnect with delay in milliseconds, set to 0 to disable.  So 3 seconds delay.
        stompClient.current.reconnectDelay = 3000;
        // Callback, invoked on every successful connection to the STOMP broker.
        stompClient.current.onConnect = handleWsConnect;
        // Callback, invoked on every successful disconnection from the STOMP broker. It will not be invoked if the STOMP broker disconnected due to an error.
        stompClient.current.onDisconnect = handleWsDisconnect;
        // Callback, invoked on an ERROR frame received from the STOMP Broker. A compliant STOMP Broker will close the connection after this type of frame
        stompClient.current.onStompError = handleWsErrors;
        // Callback, invoked when underlying WebSocket is closed.
        stompClient.current.onWebSocketClose = handleWsDisconnect;
        // Callback, invoked when underlying WebSocket raises an error
        stompClient.current.onWebSocketError = handleWsErrors;
        // Initiate the connection with the broker. If the connection breaks, as per Client#reconnectDelay,
        // it will keep trying to reconnect.
        stompClient.current.onUnhandledMessage = unhandleWsErrors;
        stompClient.current.onUnhandledReceipt = unhandleWsErrors;
        stompClient.current.onUnhandledClose = unhandleWsErrors;
        stompClient.current.onUnhandledFrame = unhandleWsErrors;

        // Initiate the connection with the broker. If the connection breaks, as per
        // Client#reconnectDelay, it will keep trying to reconnect.
        stompClient.current.activate();

        wsSetupComplete.current = true; // Websocket setup is now complete
   }

   /*
   This is only called when the page is redrawn.

   Note:  The main page is being redrawn as new stuff is added causing useEffect to setup
   the socket overhead over and over again.  So I move the logic into a function which will
   only be run once.  The comment esint-disable-next-line is suppressing the
   warning message that connectAndSetupOnlyOnce function is not a dependency of useEffect,
   which ok since this is constructor for App.js.
   */
   useEffect(() => {
        connectAndSetupOnlyOnce();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
   }, []);

   /*
    This callback sets the wsConnected to true.
    */
    function handleWsConnect() {
        console.log(' ------------ WS CONNECTED! ------------ ');
        setWsConnected(true);
    }

    /*
    This callback will update wsConnected status to false.

    @param event Event object
    */
    function handleWsDisconnect(event) {
        console.error(' ------------ WS DISCONNECTED! ------------ ');
        if (typeof(event) != "undefined") {
            let newDate = new Date();
            newDate.setTime(event.timeStamp);
            console.log('Disconnect from websocket at : ' + newDate.toUTCString() + " reason : " + event.reason);
        }
        setWsConnected(false);
      }

    /*
    This callback will logged the error update wsConnected status to false.

    @param frame Event object

    Note:
    Complaint brokers will set `message` header with a brief message. Body may contain details.
    Compliant brokers will terminate the connection after any error
    */
    function handleWsErrors(frame) {
        console.error(' ------------ WS Error! ----------- ');
        setWsConnected(false);

        if (typeof(frame) != "undefined") {
            console.log('Broker reported error: ' + frame.headers['message']);
            console.log('Additional details: ' + frame.body);
        }
      }

    /*
    This callback will logged the error, update wsConnected status to false.

    @param frame Event object
    */
    function unhandleWsErrors(frame) {
        console.error(' ------------ unhandled WS Errors! ----------- ');
        setWsConnected(false);

        if (typeof(frame) != "undefined") {
            console.log('Broker reported error: ' + frame.headers['message']);
            console.log('Additional details: ' + frame.body);
        }
      }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar wsConnected={wsConnected}></Navbar>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<NavLayout />}>
                  <Route exact index element={<Mcd stompClient={stompClient.current}/>} />
                  <Route exact path="location" element={<LocationTool stompClient={stompClient.current} wsConnected={wsConnected}/>} />
                  <Route exact path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The errors I am seeing on start up when backend is not up:

On the old version I would see this error message on each connect try.

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /ws/info?t=1666207747739 from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

etc.

The new code starts out like that, but then after some retries "upgrades" and the ECONNRESET errors start.  After reading many posts I found this is a middle-ware problem.  There are lots of attempts to "fix it" so the error doesn't happen, but none of them worked for me.  However; https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1642 says in the end of you want to stop the error being written out, "You can setup logging for http-proxy-middleware, there are options for it".  I have tried to setup an

```
on: {proxyReq, error, etc. calling console.log in each function}
```

in createProxyMiddleware options in setupProxy.js and not one console log appeared in the browser console.  So, does anyone know how setup logging so that I can filter out this message?

```
[HPM] WebSocket error: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is the minimum amount of code. I showed what the code was initially and how I ported to the last versions.   This allows people to see what was changed and the errors that are now happening.  Removing it, would make it impossible for someone to respond.